# Calendar month is displaying in center

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying python and Tkinter the first time, below is the two output of same code on Tkinter page and Console, as you can see they doesn't look the same, they are not justified the same way, the one on Tkinter page is center justified. Can any one help me understand how to display it the way it is printer on Console section on the image below:

**Code :**

```
 Label(frame, text=calander.get_calender(), fg='white', bg='black', font=(font_style, 12)).pack(side=LEFT)
```

**get_calender() method :**

```
def get_calender():
    date_today = date.today()
    year, month = date_today.strftime('%Y'), date_today.strftime('%m')
    return calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.MONDAY).formatmonth(int(year),int(month))
```

**Tkinter page :**

[image]

**Console :**

[image]

Comment: In Tkinter, the font is not monospaced. In the console, the font is monospaced by default - every character is the same width, which is why they line up nicely in the console.

Comment: @user10987432: Is there any workaround other than manipulating response string with adding one space character where there is single digit ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the font of the label to "TkFixedFont" - this is the standard Tkinter monospaced fixed width font.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from datetime import datetime
        import calendar

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Calendar")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        today = datetime.today()
        year, month = today.year, today.month
        text_calendar = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.MONDAY).formatmonth(year, month)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=text_calendar, font="TkFixedFont", justify=tk.LEFT, fg="white", bg="black")
        self.label.pack()


def main():
    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

[image]

Comment: But last date is still in the middle :

Comment: Sorry about that, just noticed it too. I've updated my answer. All I did was add the `justify` keyword argument to the label.